# What is a pkcs#11 secret key

Tags: cryptography, pkcs#11

http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/csprd02/pkcs11-base-v2.40-csprd02-COMMENT-TAGS.html lists three types of key objects: `CKO_PUBLIC_KEY`, `CKO_PRIVATE_KEY` and `CKO_SECRET_KEY`.

What is the use case for a `CKO_SECRET_KEY` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKO_SECRET_KEY are keys for symmetric cryptography (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm).

While CKO_PUBLIC_KEY and CKO_PRIVATE_KEY are keys for asymmetric cryptography (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).